# Simplify TiKz chain diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

TiKz chain is amazing tool,I am reading [Chains with labeled edges](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/) example.

This example use matrix to place nodes, then use chain to connect it together. it's fine of course but I am thinking about if we can just place the nodes and then the chain will connect it automatically.

So I just write a simple example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,matrix,positioning,scopes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{>=stealth',every on chain/.append style={join},
         every join/.style={->}}
\tikzstyle{labeled}=[execute at begin node=$\scriptstyle,
   execute at end node=$]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node (A) {A};
   \node [right=of A] (B) {B};
  { [start chain] \chainin (A);
    \chainin (B) [join={node[above,labeled] {\eta_1}}];;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It works perfect now but I am wondering if we can combine the node statements with the draw statement together. Maybe looks like below (it doesn't work of course now)!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  { [start chain] \chainin \node (A) {A};;
    \chainin \node [right=of A] (B) {B}; [join={node[above,labeled] {\eta_1}}];;
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Is it possible to make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply say `on chain` to make a node joined to a chain. And also with TikZ v3.00 it is easier to add labels to edges.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning,scopes,quotes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
{[start chain]
   \node[on chain] (A) {A};
   \node[on chain,join=by {->,"$\eta_1$"},right=of A] (B) {B};
   \node[on chain,join=by {<-,"$\eta_2$"},right=of B] (C) {C};
   \node[on chain,join=by {bend left,->,"$\int dx$"},right=of C] (D) {D};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, so the example should be changed to use TiKz 3.00. :-).

Comment: @Beatlej Not necessarily. With that example it works pretty OK. Note that it is from 2011 so allow for some decay